# PWA APP icon on iOS has unnecessary padding

Tags: ios, web-applications, icons, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a pwa app. On iOS when I try to add it to home screen, the app icon has padding that I can't get rid of.

[image]

I am using many different size icons in manifest as well as meta tag apple-touch-icon.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="public/icons/icon-72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="public/icons/icon-144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="public/icons/icon-120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="public/icons/icon-152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="public/icons/icon-180.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="public/icons/icon-192.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="1024x1024" href="public/icons/icon-1024.png">
```

Manifest file (only showing few icons than there are in the actual manifest file, for reference) -

```
 {
            src: "icons/icon-192.png",
            sizes: "192x192",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "any",
          },
          {
            src: "icons/icon-256.png",
            sizes: "256x256",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "any",
          },
          {
            src: "icons/icon-512.png",
            sizes: "512x512",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "any",
          },
          {
            src: "icons/icon-1024.png",
            sizes: "1024x1024",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "any",
          },
          {
            src: "icons/icon-48.png",
            sizes: "48x48",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "maskable",
          },
          {
            src: "icons/icon-72.png",
            sizes: "72x72",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "maskable",
          },
          {
            src: "icons/icon-96.png",
            sizes: "96x96",
            type: "image/png",
            purpose: "maskable",
          },
```

Anyone knows why the icons have this unnecessary padding or what perfect size to use for iOS?